# Why do I get "no route matches" for requests to the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm working on upgrading an app to use Rails 3.1 and I'm trying to use the asset pipeline. As a test, I've added `foobar.js` to `app/assets/javascripts`.

### The Setup

In `application.rb`, I've added `config.assets.enabled = true`. Going on [this guide](http://ryanbigg.com/guides/asset_pipeline.html#adding-assets-to-your-gems), I think that's all I have to do.

### Checking it out

If I load the console and check `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`, I do see `app/assets/javascripts` in the load path. Also, if I check `MyAppName::Application.assets`, I get back a `Sprockets::Environment` object which has the same paths.

That all looks good to me.

### Trying to use it

In a view, I'm using `javascript_include_tag('foobar')`. That outputs the following HTML: `<script src="/javascripts/foobar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

### The error

Following that link gets me an error: `No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/foobar.js"`

**Is there a piece of setup I'm missing?**

---

### Misc Details

I'm currently using:

- ruby-1.9.2-p290
- rails-3.1.0.rc6
- sprockets-2.0.0.beta.14 (required by Rails)

Comment: I still had to add the files manually to the pipeline (see https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails.rb). I guess it's because Rails 3.1 is still in beta

Comment: @apneadiving - progress! Doing that **does** get foobar.js loaded. Next I tried loading a manifest file, which has `//= require` statements in it. That file is sent to the browser without processing; the `require` statements are just treated as comments instead of processing the specified files. Ideas?

Comment: mmm, don't know: it worked properly for me: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/public/javascripts/gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js

Comment: @apneadiving - My boneheaded mistake. :) My manifest file had a dot in it, like `MyRailsEngine.manifest.js`. I think that made Rails/Sprockets try to processes it as a `manifest` file, which it doesn't know how to do. Not sure why it it didn't throw an error, but anyway, changing it to `MyRailsEngine-manifest.js` works fine.

Comment: @apneadiving - So, basically, your first comment solved my problem. Want to add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: weird behavior yep! good to know though :) Did I answer your question?

Comment: damn we are connected ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still had to add the files manually to the pipeline (see [link](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails.rb)).

I guess it's because Rails 3.1 is still in beta

Comment: Hey - I think we're actually doing this wrong. Your trick got things working for me, but I had my `application.js` in `public/javascripts/`, which we added to the load path in your initializer. When I moved the file to `app/assets/javascripts/`, I didn't need the initializer anymore, because `app/assets/javascripts/` was already on the load path.

Comment: ok thanks :) Indeed, I keep everything in `public/javascripts` to maintain Rails 3.0.x compatibility